# WPF Binding не работает

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

привет есть код XAML, но он не работает

```
<Grid Name="mainGrid" Background="#EEE">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60*" Name="mainGridcentre"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="15*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid  Name="centerGrid" 
               Grid.Row="1"
               Background="Black"
               Panel.ZIndex="1"
               Width="{Binding ElementName=mainGridcentre, Path=Height}" 
               ShowGridLines="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="#14BDAC"></Border> 
        <Label FontWeight="Bold" 
               Background="#14BDAC" 
               Width="200" Height="50" 
               Content="НАЧАТЬ ЗАНОВО"
               Grid.Row="2" FontSize="20" 
               FontStyle="Normal" 
               Foreground="White" 
               ForceCursor="True" 
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
               VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></Label>
    </Grid>
```

а именно не работает привязка ширины к высоте строки другого грида

```
Width="{Binding ElementName=mainGridcentre, Path=Height}" ShowGridLines="True"
```

Comment: "не рабит" - not rabbit? кролики?

Comment: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2J7csEa8tYM/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: У вас Grid называется `mainGrid` а вы пытаетесь привязать к  `mainGridcentre`?

Comment: Ну и пробуйте привязывать к  `ActualHeight`

Comment: нет вы не поняли мне надо не высоту грида а высоту 2 строки грида

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените `Height` на `ActualHeight` в биндинге:

```
Width="{Binding ElementName=mainGridcentre, Path=ActualHeight}"
```

Подробнее про `RowDefenition.ActualHeight` можете почитать [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.rowdefinition.actualheight.aspx).

Comment: И добавьте Mode к биндингу. Да и должно нормально с mode отработать если биндить Width.